# (HTML) привязка таблицы к нижней линии границы страницы

Tags: html, css, table

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html >
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   @page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    body { margin: 1.6cm; padding-top: 72px;
padding-bottom: 72px ; }
}
@media print {
.header-left-top,.header-left-bottom, .a-right-bottom, .time-right-bottom {
display: none;
}
}
 .fig {
    display: block; /* Блочный элемент (для старых браузеров) */
    text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по центру */
    font-style: italic; /* Курсивное начертание */
    margin-top: 0; /* Отступ сверху */
    margin-bottom: 5px; /* Отступ снизу */
    color: #666; /* Цвет подрисуночной подписи */
   }
   .space { /* Рисуем поля  */
     height: 1200px;
        width: 800px;
margin-left: 76px;
margin-top: 19px;
margin-right: 19px;
margin-bottom: 19px;
border-left-style: ridge;
border-left: 2px; 
border-right: 2px ;
border-top: 2px;
border-bottom: 2px;
border-bottom: 2px;
border: 3px solid #000;
font-family:  "Times New Roman";

  }

</style>
 </head >
 <body class="page" class="print">
   <div class="space" class="print">


   <!-- Нижняя часть таблица -->

  <table  border="solid"  width="100%" color=black height= "5%" ; style="color: black ;table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; padding-top: 10px;  "     > <tr  style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%">
       
        <td></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td rowspan="3" width="200"></td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">Лист </td>
     <!--   <td rowspan="2">123</td> -->
    </tr>
    <tr height="15">
        <td ></td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
      <td><div style="font-size: 7px;"></div> </td>

        <td rowspan="2" align="center" style="font-size: 8px;"> 1</td>
        
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8px;">1</td>
        <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8px;">2 </td>
        <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8px;">3</td>
        <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8px;">4 </td>
        <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8px;">5</td>
        <td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 8px;">6</td>

         
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
     
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть такой код таблицы, нужно эту таблицу привязать к чёрной полоски снизу... Как это возможно сделать? пробовал способом привязать к низу страницы, но он работал криво. 
В коде почти каждая строчка за комментирована, так что понять мой код я надеюсь не составит труда.
В итоге должно получиться следующее
[image: Пример как он будет смотреться в конечном варианте]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.space {
  position: relative;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Добавьте этот стиль. Если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё верно поняли!